# Knockout Computed not updating?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
    self.isViewingFolder = ko.observable();
    self.isViewingSet = ko.observable();
    self.canEditFolder = ko.observable();

    self.isViewingFolder(ko.computed(function() {
        return router.activeRoute().moduleId == 'viewmodels/folder';
    }));
    self.isViewingSet(ko.computed(function () {
        return router.activeRoute().moduleId == 'viewmodels/set';
    }));
    self.canEditFolder(ko.computed(function() {
        return self.isViewingFolder() && auth.isAuthenticated() && !self.isPublicFolder()
    }));
```

isViewingFolder and isViewingSet are always updating as expected, though canEditFolder is only updating one time.  If I set canEditFolder to

```
canEditFolder(isViewingFolder())
```

Then it works, but I need logic in there so I'm using a computed observable.  Why wouldn't this be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening, is that the observables in the in the first 2 functions are not cascading their updates to the higher observables.  canEditFolder without isViewingFolder() as an argument assesses it's initial value, it then later doesn't receive the update, and therefore needs a new argument to tell it to update its value.

Now then since canEditFolder will always be equal to isViewingFolder why do you need the extra function?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I need the function because more logic will eventually go into determining the value of canEdit.  I just tried defining a separate computed observable and then updating canEditFolder() with that, but it's still not updating.  How could this be fixed if the function is needed?

Comment: is router.activeRoute().moduleId observable? As the only way to have a computed reassess is to have an observable object throw a update event or provide a new element to assess against(your hacky solution).   something like var dummy = ko.observab

Comment: isViewingFolder and isViewing set are working fine - moduleId is not an observable.  They are both observables and are updating correctly - so why isn't canEditFolder catching them?

Comment: isViewingFolder, and isViewing are computed functions not observables, as a result their changes will not cascade.

Comment: But I defined them as ko.observable() and then assigned their value